# Responsive Navigation through jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to get my navigation bar to work with resizing. 
It is converted to a select option when the screen size gets reduced. 

It works but the problem is when the screen size is reduced the first option is shown in the select box instead of the current option.

I want the select box to stay at the current selected option.

---

**Here is my code**

```
jQuery('<select />').appendTo('#navigation');

jQuery('#navigation a').each(function () {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('<option />', {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
    }).appendTo('#navigation select');
});

jQuery('#navigation select').change(function () {
    window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

---

Is there any fault in my jQuery code? Please help me to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (assuming a link has class "selected" when active)

```
jQuery('<select />').appendTo('#navigation');

jQuery('#navigation a').each(function () {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    var current = jQuery('<option />', {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
    });

    url = document.URL.split('/');
    if(url[url.length-1] == current.attr('value'))
        current.prop('selected', true);
    current.appendTo('#navigation select');
});

jQuery('#navigation select').change(function () {
    window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

For the second template (remove the `<select>` you already got there):

```
jQuery('<select />').appendTo('#navigation');

jQuery('#menu-new-main-menu li a').each(function () {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    var current = jQuery('<option />', {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
    });

    if(document.URL == current.attr('value'))
        current.prop('selected', true);
    current.appendTo('#navigation select');
});

jQuery('#navigation select').change(function () {
    window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Comment: There is no selected class getting added to the option field on selection. I guess that is the main problem. How can I add selected class to the current option?

Comment: Can you add a link to the page so I can see what is going on there? don't you style the current page link differently then the rest?

Comment: I am actually working on localhost but yes I am using this template - http://webcodebuilder.com/envato/showcase/blog.html

Comment: Updated. I took a different approach since the template does not mark the current page link. I've retrieved the URL using `document.URL` and then comared the last part of it (e.g. `blog.html`) to the current link address.. if a match is found - add property `selected`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with the html template, can you also make it work with this kind of navigation code - http://pastebin.com/Rie0W4qg

Comment: did as you said but now the default option is the last option and even after selecting an option, last option is shown in the select field.

Comment: Oops! I missed one line, thank you very much it is working good now :)